Remapping telescope's move_selection doesn't work
New to vim. Using Dvorak layout. Trying to remap the move_selection_{next,previous} to t for next and c for previous, to match my text editing mappings. Here's the code:
  {
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    keys = {
      -- add a keymap to browse plugin files
      -- stylua: ignore
      {
        "<leader>fp",
        function() require("telescope.builtin").find_files({ cwd = require("lazy.core.config").options.root }) end,
        desc = "Find Plugin File",
      },
    },
    -- change some options
    opts = {
      defaults = {
        layout_strategy = "horizontal",
        layout_config = { prompt_position = "top" },
        sorting_strategy = "ascending",
        winblend = 0,
      },
      mappings = {
        n = {
          ["t"] = require("telescope.actions").move_selection_next,
          ["c"] = require("telescope.actions").move_selection_previous,
        },
      },
    },
  },

This just doesn't work.
It acts the same regardless of weather I specify the mappings or not. When I press t, it opens the highlighted file in fullscreen (with the telescope window hidden), and on c it says "copy <filename> to: <enter-name>". This is especially weird because I've looked at the default telescope mappings and there aren't any for these keys. If there's some global action on top of telescope mapped to these keys, then why do they work correctly when I'm just editing a file?

I realized the file picker that shows up on the left is NOT telescope. That's why changing the mappings wasn't doing anything.

My setup works:
return {
  {
    'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim',
    tag = '0.1.8',
    dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' },
    config = function()
      local builtin = require('telescope.builtin')
      vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ff', builtin.find_files, {})
      vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})
      vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fb', builtin.buffers, {})
      vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fh', builtin.help_tags, {})
    end
  },
  {
    'nvim-telescope/telescope-ui-select.nvim',
    config = function()
      local actions = require("telescope.actions")
      require("telescope").setup({
        defaults = {
          mappings = {
            i = {
              ["<C-k>"] = actions.move_selection_previous,
              ["<C-j>"] = actions.move_selection_next,
            }
          }
        },
        extensions = {
          ["ui-select"] = {
            require("telescope.themes").get_dropdown {
            }
          }
        }
      })
      require("telescope").load_extension("ui-select")
    end
  }
}


Welcome to the site and thank you for writing an answer. The greatest answers on this site contain some code and explain why and how this code solves the question. You can always [edit] and improve your answer.
